# Oscillon and soliton

Tags: quantum-field-theory, terminology, field-theory, solitons

I want to know the major difference between [oscillon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oscillon) and [soliton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soliton) in terms of radiating energy with respect to time and position. And what about their localization?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean by "radiating energy with respect to time and position", could you try to make it clearer?

Comment: I mean if  oscillon or solition  radiates energy then will they depends on time?

Comment: Clearly if something radiates then you have time dependence, yes.

Comment: This might help (Nature Article):  Oscillons, solitons, and domain walls in arrays of nonlinear plasmonic nanoparticles http://www.nature.com/srep/2012/121119/srep00873/full/srep00873.html

Answer (score 2):

Solitons do NOT radiate energy, and are localised. One definition of soliton is:

"Solitons are non-singular, static, finite energy solutions of the
classical field equations."

(taken from Maciej Dunajski's book 'Solitons, Instantons, and Twistors').

I've never heard of "oscillons" before.